# invalid label json label vs javascript label

Tags: javascript

I get invalid label error for **"firstname": "John2",**.
I put my json data in parenthesis, so why am I still getting this error? 
Am I still lacking something so that the code is confusing it with a java script label?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = "(" + {
  "firstname": "John1",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "48.4048403957642",
    "longitude": "2.68452644348145"
  }
}
{
  "firstname": "John2",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "48.4050236871384",
    "longitude": "2.68512690051361"
  }
}
{
  "firstname": "John3",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "48.4048403957642",
    "longitude": "2.68452644348145"
  }
}
+ ")" ;

      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var location = data[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,
              location.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: see this short [article](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1161-json-ajax-jquery-jsonp-getjson.html) about jquery json use and i'm with 'quentin' answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems (that I can spot).

First, you are working in JavaScript, not JSON. You have an object literal.

Get rid of the `"("` and `")"` entirely. Those are used if you are trying to parse JSON using `eval`. You don't have JSON and if you did you should use the `JSON` object (and its `parse` method), not `eval`. Currently, you are trying to stringify the object (which would give you something like `"([Object object])"`, which wouldn't be any use at all).

Second, you appear to be trying to work with an array of objects, but you have just placed them one after the other.

Wrap your objects with an array literal `[` and `]`.

Separate the items in the array with commas (`,`).

The reason for the error message is that you have created such a weird parse state that the JS engine things you are trying to [label a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: I understand your points but I am simply to trying to make google maps work just like here and this is how they did it? http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it easier to use a JSON generating function? For example:

```
function array2json(arr) {
var parts = [];
var is_list = (Object.prototype.toString.apply(arr) === '[object Array]');

for (var key in arr) {
    var value = arr[key];
    if(typeof value == "object") { //Custom handling for arrays
        if(is_list) parts.push(array2json(value)); /* :RECURSION: */
        else parts[key] = array2json(value); /* :RECURSION: */
    } else {
        var str = "";
        if(!is_list) str = '"' + key + '":';

        //Custom handling for multiple data types
        if(typeof value == "number") str += value; //Numbers
        else if(value === false) str += 'false'; //The booleans
        else if(value === true) str += 'true';
        else str += '"' + value + '"'; //All other things
        // :TODO: Is there any more datatype we should be in the lookout for? (Functions?)

        parts.push(str);
    }
}
var json = parts.join(",");

if(is_list) return '[' + json + ']';//Return numerical JSON
return '{' + json + '}';//Return associative JSON
}
```

(*Sidenote: I did not make this code myself, but it's very useful!*)

You can make JSON data using:

```
myJSON = array2json(['any data', {'even objects': 'can go in here'});
```

And you can get the array back using:

```
var myArray = eval('(' + myJSON + ')');
```

Comment: Since the object is to loop over the data structure in the same script, no, creating a JSON object wouldn't be at all useful.

Comment: `var myArray = eval('(' + myJSON + ')');`? In 2012? That is **awful** advice. As is using some copy/paste JS to create JSON, instead of using the native JSON object (with a standard, well documented library with a known location for bug reports such as json2.js)

Comment: I am not trying to generate Json data here. I want to use data from the already created json data.

Comment: Never mind then, this is was I always use, and until now it has worked very well.